# using container with page view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

For my current app, I am setting up a UIPageViewController to swap between 3 different views. I don't plan to add any Navigation Bar, so I added a Close Button to navigate the user back to the home screen. However, I want the position of the Close button as fixed on the top right. So I used a container in a ViewController to call the other view controller with the images and text, as in below:[image]

Here, the Page View Controller directs to Container View Controller with embedded segue to Look Up Page Content Controller.

At the moment in the respective class for Page View Controller i have;
// MARK:- Other Methods

```
func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> LookUpPageContentViewController
{
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containerLookUp") as! LookUpPageContentViewController

    pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
    pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
    pageContentViewController.strMainTitle = "\(arrMainTitle[index])"
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

    pageContentViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.dondeBeigeColor()

    return pageContentViewController
}
```

This method however directs to the Look Up Page Content View Controller. How can i change this method to call the Container View Controller which then calls the Look Up Page Content Controller.

Answer (score 0):

by reading your problem am assuming the structure

```
-> PageViewController
 -> ContainerView 
  -> LookupView controller
```

So on tapping, you should load containerView first. like below

```
ContainerViewController*containerView =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: CONTAINER_VIEWCONTROLLER_ID];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:switchView animated:YES];
```

On ContainerViewController viewDidLoad method, Do this

```
LookUpPageContentViewController*lookUpView = // Get the Appropirate LookupView
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[lookUpView] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This will get you the feature you want.Hope this will help you.